# Advice making a multi line chart with daily count data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

This is what my raw data looks like:

[image: raw data image]

I would like to use this data to create a chart that display's Install date in the X axis, a daily sum of records for each installed by name in the Y axis and a line for each InstalledBy name. I was able to create a pivot chart that is able to sum up each individuals daily sum:

[image: pivot chart]

But I can't make a pivot chart from this data :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

1. Select data range
2. excel --> Insert --> Pivot Table --> Pivot Chart --> Ok
3. Then assign each column into required fields as below screen-shot.

[image]